# Miner not picking pending transactions from pool when TPS is high

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, pending-transactions, txpool

I'm running a private testnet with a high block gas limit and low difficulty. When I start pumping in a large volume of transactions (say 150 tx/s), after a certain point of time, I see the miner mining just empty blocks, despite there being a large number of transactions in the miner's tx pool. Any idea about why this might be happening?

Comment: I have the same problem. I assume that the tx pools start to drop transactions if the tx pool is full. The TX pool seems to have an upper limit of tx per account. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go#L80-L83

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out mitchkman - I had the same suspicion. But then it should at least mine the transactions that have been admitted in the pool.